# Python/HTML/JS How to get raw input

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Hi im working on a tool with python and flask that does operations on a file, instead of taking in a file using a multi part form, i want the user to be able to enter **text** as raw input, which is the location of the file that the operations would be done on. This is a webapp, so the main index html would have a text box to enter the location of the file and next, it would do the operations on it once upload is clicked.
Currently i have only figuired out how to do this using a multi part form, however i want to be able to enter"            'C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\somefolder\newn.txt' once that is entered and submit button is pressed it would find that file on the laptop and open it and perform the operations
is this possible i keep getting into a error basically where it isnt able to convert the text to a filetype....so it doesnt get to open the entered file...

Comment: Show us what you're been trying to do and what didn't work.

Comment: The error im getting right now is that it states that str object has no attribute 'file' or 'save' i know the reason for this error since im taking in raw text, however how can i convert raw text to a file type?

Comment: ERROR: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Please post the code as a [mcve]. High-level English descriptions are nice to provide intent and context, but without the concrete code, descriptions leave way too much to the imagination on their own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to obtain the text with python, what you can do is put this text into a **text file**.
To do so, you could do the following:

```
with open("your_file.txt", "w") as file:
     file.write(your_text)

     # If you want to perform some file operations with file variable
```

This would create a file named *your_text.txt*, where you will be able to perform file operations.